# Limiting size of jpa association query

Tags: jpa, entity, resultset

The following query gets all the employees in the department:

```
List<Employee> employees = em.find(Department.class,departmentid).getEmployeeList();
```

However, i am looking to get only a limited number of results from the above query and not complete resultset.  Is it possible via the above query?

I am aware of em.createQuery() alternative however would like to use the existing one-to-many association in the entity and not write a new query to get limited results.

Any help or ideas would be great.

Comment: No, it's not possible. You have to use a query and set its max results.

Comment: I think so too, you have to use for example FetchType.Lazy and then write a query that does JOIN FETCH to get the results. Or create a Named Query or use CriteriaBuilder if you don't like writing JPQL.

Answer (score 2):

Use JPQL,

```
Select e from Department d join d.employees e where d.id = :id
```

And set the maxResults on the query